# Failed to import bridging-header, mapbox-iOS-SDK/Mapbox.h file not found! Swift 3 Xcode 8

Tags: swift3, xcode8, bridging-header

i'm getting the following errors:

- 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK/Mapbox.h' file not found
- Failed to import bridging header

I tried already:

- Making a new bridging header
- Changing the bridging header path
- Changing the framework search paths
- Installing my pods again
- ....

I hope someone has an answer for this :)

thx

Comment: Do you have `use_frameworks!` set in your pod file? If so you don't need to import this in the bridging header, you can import is directly into your swift code. `import Mapbox` should do the trick.

Comment: use frameworks isn't an option at this moment..

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `use_frameworks!` in your pod file and `platform` supported by pod. If it not helps 
**Restart Xcode**. In any weird situation just restart Xcode as it seems to have plenty of bugs. I hope this helps.